# Slick.js carousel too much space and sliding issue

Tags: javascript, slick.js

I am using slick.js  https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/ . The issue is I am trying to slide containg rows sliding cards (".carosalItemHash") . Each row contain cards and it should be adjacent to previous cards avoiding too much empty spaces. One tap of arrow, slide should be such that each card is visible.

I am trying two show elements in a 2 rows using slick.js such that it should slide horizontally.

1) Space shoulds not be there. The spaces must be filled with another card next to it.
2) Each cards in a row should slide one by one such that each card text is completely visible on sliding one by one.

[image: ick]

## .html

```
    <div class="skillsCntr uttPanel">\
                <div class="carosalItemHash" style="border-bottom: 0px;">\
                    <span title="">cqqcc</span>
                </div>
                <div class="carosalItemHash" style="border-bottom: 0px;">\
                    <span title="">cqqcc</span>
                </div>
     <div class="carosalItemHash" style="border-bottom: 0px;">\
                    <span title="">cqqcc</span>
                </div>
     <div class="carosalItemHash" style="border-bottom: 0px;">\
                    <span title="">cqqcc</span>
                </div>
     <div class="carosalItemHash" style="border-bottom: 0px;">\
                    <span title="">cqqcc</span>
                </div>
            </div>\


js
=========


const slider = $(".skillsCntr.utterancePanel");
                    slider
                        .slick({
                            arrows: true,
                            infinite: true,
                            slidesPerRow: 1,
                            rows: 2,
                            slidesToShow: 4,
                            slidesToScroll: 1,
                            dots: false,
                            autoplay: false,
                            // speed: 300,
                            variableWidth: true,
                            centerMode: true,
                            adaptiveHeight: false,
                            centerPadding: '0%'
                        });
                    //Implementing navigation of slides using mouse scroll
                    slider.on('wheel', (function (e) {
                        e.preventDefault();



             if (e.originalEvent.deltaY < 0) {
                                $(this).slick('slickNext');
                            } else {
                                $(this).slick('slickPrev');
                            }
                        }));
                    }

<head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.6.0/slick/slick.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.6.0/slick/slick-theme.css" />
</head>
<body>
  <div class="skillsCntr uttPanel">\
                <div class="carosalItemHash" style="border-bottom: 0px;">\
                    <span title="">cqqcc</span>
                </div>
                <div class="carosalItemHash" style="border-bottom: 0px;">\
                    <span title="">cqqcc</span>
                </div>
     <div class="carosalItemHash" style="border-bottom: 0px;">\
                    <span title="">cqqcc</span>
                </div>
     <div class="carosalItemHash" style="border-bottom: 0px;">\
                    <span title="">cqqcc</span>
                </div>
     <div class="carosalItemHash" style="border-bottom: 0px;">\
                    <span title="">cqqcc</span>
                </div>
            </div>\
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.6.0/slick/slick.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Did you try `centerPadding: 0`? No string, no extras, just the number zero

Comment: Yes, but the space between two texts in each row is too much and also on sliding it is sliding to left or right skipping 3 to 4 cards in between, so unable to view each text on slide.

Comment: take out the slidesToShow option, with centerMode you're only showing 1. The space between the two texts shouldn't be related to Slick Slider, you just need some CSS to set `margin: 0;` for those spans or whatever they are

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I've got all the requested changes, but I created a simple version with two lines per slide, having no spacing between the lines. One slide of two lines is shown at a time.

The settings are:

```
$(".uttPanel").slick({
    arrows: true,
    infinite: true,
    slidesPerRow: 1,
    rows: 2,
    dots: false,
    autoplay: false,
);
```

A codepen with minimal JS and CSS is here: https://codepen.io/edlucas/pen/PowRyRe

I hope this helps.

Comment: Slick does seem to have trouble with centerMode and multiple rows.

Comment: There is a lot of space in each row and the text in each row are not continuous ie other text should immediately come after previous text with little equal space between them in 2 rows. On Swiping, the texts should be visible and readable.

Comment: Yes, that's the problem with centerMode not seeming to work with two rows.